# Laravel eloquent where with relationship

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent, relation

I am stuck on transforming this SQL query to an eloquent query in Laravel. The SQL query works (tested in Sequel) but I cannot write it in eloquent ...

```
SELECT faqs.question FROM faqs
JOIN categories c ON c.id = faqs.category_id
WHERE c.subsite = 'sport'
```

---

This is what I have tried so far, but it returns all the questions, (ignoring the subsite filter).

```
$cat = Faq::with(['category' => function($query) use ($subsite) {
    $query->where('subsite', $subsite);
}])->get();
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$cat = Faq::query();
if (isset($subsite) && !empty($subsite) {
  $query->whereHas('category', function ($query) use ($subsite) {
            $query->where('subsite', $subsite);
        });
}
$query->with('category')->get();
```

Comment: sorry its my mistake use $query instead of $cat

Comment: You can call `->get()` directly on the `$query` in the if statement, no need for the extra line. (edit that and the typo to your answer so I can mark it as solution?)

Comment: I have tried to suggest an edit on your answer but some people didn't look at it long enough to see my point was valid. Anyhow, if you can change it I can mark it as an answer!

Answer (score 0):

as per you core sql query, here is your laravel query.

```
$data = DB::table('faqs')
            ->join('categories', 'categories.id', '=', 'faqs.category_id')
            ->select('faqs.question')
            ->where('categories.subsite', '=', 'sport')
            ->get();
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Thanks, this does indeed work! I wanted to try the eloquent way, nor using pure SQL queries. Anyway, this is my backup now ;)